# Android - TextView maxWidth weird issue

Tags: java, android, textview, android-relativelayout, css

I have the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:textColor="#ededed"
                android:fadeScrollbars="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the code I use the following to set the maxWidth size which is customizable by the user:

```
textview.setMaxWidth(768);
```

The issue I'm facing is, the maxWidth setting only works up to what seems like 620px.  Anything above that has no effect.  If I set the textview width to 768px it stil has no effect but if I set the relative layout width to 768px then the textview maxWidth works above 620px.

So it seems the issue is the relative layout isn't wrapping as expected and is limiting the width.  I don't want to have to set a static width on the relative layout as this would defeat the purpose (for my application) of using a maxWidth inside it.  And this issue isn't device specific either, it seems to cap at that point on any device.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening or how I can work around it without specifying a static with for the relative layout?

Comment: But why do you need `maxWidth` such long though you have `match_parent` there?

Comment: Because I've made it customization by the user, they can increase it up to 620px but anything after that has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the core issue that you would like the contents of your textView to wrap?  If so, you might want to look here: [How to line wrap Android TextView views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769852/how-to-line-wrap-android-textview-views)

Comment: No this is not the issue at all.